# Bot Telegram feito em Python - Não consigo enviar fotos

Tags: python, telegram

Fiz um bot no Telegram para simular uma caçada Pokémon.
Estou tentando implementar que o bot envie uma foto do Pokémon quando o usuário o encontrar, mas não consigo.

```
import logging, random 
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

pokemon_list = open("pokemon.txt", encoding="utf8")
pokemons = [] 
for line in pokemon_list:
    pokemons.append(line.strip("\n"))

# Enable logging 
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# command handlers.
def start(update, context):
        update.message.reply_text(
        'Olá {}! Nosso mais novo PokeTrainer!'.format(update.message.from_user.first_name))

def help(update, context):
        update.message.reply_text('Bot desenvolvido para simular um encontro aleatório na grama alta,'
                                  ' utilizando os Pokemons da primeira geração.'
                                  '\n/start - Inicia o bot.'
                                  '\n/help - Ajuda do bot.'
                                  '\n/procurar - Procura um Pokemon na grama alta.'
                                  '\nEncontrou algum erro? Envie um email para: arthuredugood@gmail.com')

def procurar(update, context):
        pokemon = random.choice(pokemons)
        update.message.reply_text(f"Você encontrou um {pokemon}!")

def send_photo(update, context):
        bot.sendPhoto(
            chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
            photo='1.png')

# Start the bot.
def main():
    updater = Updater("1006417815:AAEE1h8QPug18Gu-d5QAHKC57Vjv_StP2G8", use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("procurar", procurar, send_photo))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em português. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no site em inglês do StackOverflow.

Comment: Olá, fiz esta [postagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/541774/103217), ela pode ajudar com a sua dificuldade.