# Enviar Foto no Telegram Bot Python

Tags: python, imagem, chatbot, telegram

Estou desenvolvendo um bot no Telegram em Python. Porém, no meu código não estou conseguindo fazer ele responder com fotos. Apenas mensagem.
Ex. Gostaria de enviar a mensagem "foto" e o bot enviasse uma foto.

```
import requests
import time
import json
import os
import telegram
import telebot


class TelegramBot:
    def __init__(self):
        token = '***'
        self.url_base = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/"


    # Iniciar
    def Iniciar(self):
        update_id = None
        while True:
            atualizacao = self.obter_novas_mensagens(update_id)
            dados = atualizacao["result"]
            if dados:
                for dado in dados:
                    update_id = dado['update_id']
                    mensagem = str(dado["message"]["text"])
                    chat_id = dado["message"]["from"]["id"]
                    eh_primeira_mensagem = int(dado["message"]["message_id"]) == 1
                    resposta = self.criar_resposta(
                        mensagem, eh_primeira_mensagem)
                    self.responder(resposta, chat_id)

    # Obter mensagens


    def obter_novas_mensagens(self, update_id):
        link_requisicao = f'{self.url_base}getUpdates?timeout=100'
        if update_id:
            link_requisicao = f'{link_requisicao}&offset={update_id + 1}'
        resultado = requests.get(link_requisicao)
        return json.loads(resultado.content)


    # Criar uma resposta
    def criar_resposta(self, mensagem, eh_primeira_mensagem):
        if eh_primeira_mensagem == True or mensagem in ('sim', 'Sim', 'SIM'):
            return f'''Escolha as opções no menu.'''
        else:
            return f'''Olá, tudo bem?'''
    # Responder


    def responder(self, resposta, chat_id):
        link_requisicao = f'{self.url_base}sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={resposta}'
        requests.get(link_requisicao)

bot = TelegramBot()
bot.Iniciar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consultando a [`documentação da apirest`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#recent-changes) de bots do Telegram, podemos verificar que existe uma chamada específica para o envio de [`fotos`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto).

Desta forma uma maneira de implementar o envio de fotos seria criando um novo método para tratar o envio com o tipo de mensagem `photo`. Além disso o envio deve ser feito via método HTTP `post`

Esse envio deve ser feito utilizando o endpoint:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/sendPhoto
```

Segue um exemplo de implementação:

```
import requests
def enviar_imagem(file_path):
    body = {
        'chat_id': chat_id,
    }
    files = {
        'photo': open(file_path, 'rb')
    }
    r = requests.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/sendPhoto'.format(
    token), data=body, files=files)
    if r.status_code >= 400:
        print('Houve um erro ao enviar mensagem. Detalhe: {}'.format(r.text))
    else:
        print('Mensagem enviada com sucesso.')
```

A foto deve ter no máximo 10 MB de tamanho. A relação entre largura e altura deve ser no máximo 20. Também existe restrição em relação à altura e largura máxima da imagem. [`Consultar limites e restrições`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputfile) da API do Telegram.

Usamos a função embutida `open` com os parâmetros `'rb'`, isso vai
abrir um arquivo e retornar um objeto arquivo correspondente. Se o arquivo não puder ser aberto, uma exceção do tipo `OSError` é lançada. O parâmetro que utilizamos foi o modo leitura ('r') e ler os binários do arquivo ('b'). Consulte a [`documentação`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#open) para mais exemplos de como usar esta função.

Se deseja fazer o envio de uma foto que já está nos servidores do Telegram, basta enviar a mensagem passando o `file_id` como um parâmetro, desta forma não é necessário fazer o upload do arquivo. Neste caso a forma de envio será um pouco diferente:

```
def enviar_imagem_por_id(file_id):
    body = {
        'chat_id': chat_id,
        'photo': file_id
    }

    r = requests.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/sendPhoto'.format(token), data=body)
    if r.status_code >= 400:
        print('Houve um erro ao enviar mensagem. Detalhe: {}'.format(r.text))
    else:
        print('Mensagem enviada com sucesso')
```

Se você ver a mensagem de sucesso no console, será possível ver a imagem (foto) no Telegram.

Esta implementação assume que está utilizando a biblioteca [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) do python3.

Answer (score -1):

Creio que com python-telegram-bot será mais simples o que deseja fazer.
https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#post-an-image-file-from-disk

Segue um pequeno exemplo de envio de imagens

```
bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=open('tests/test.png', 'rb'))
```